# many to many select statement incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have noticed an error in my sql query but I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
SELECT blog_posts.postid, 
       blog_posts.posttitle, 
       blog_posts.postdesc, 
       blog_posts.postdate 
FROM   blog_posts 
       INNER JOIN members_posts 
               ON members_posts.memberid = blog_posts.postid 
WHERE  members_posts.memberid = '1'
```

In the above I am trying to select only the posts belonging to the memberID='1'. Nothing is being displayed though?

Comment: What's the "error" you noticed?  Do you see an error message or do you just see 0 rows?  A query returning no rows is not an error, per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT bp.postID, bp.postTitle, bp.postDesc, bp.postDate
FROM blog_posts bp INNER JOIN
     members_posts mp
     ON mp.memberID = bp.postID
-----------^ ------------^ That seems unlikely
WHERE mp.memberID = '1';
```

Use the correct column:

```
SELECT bp.postID, bp.postTitle, bp.postDesc, bp.postDate
FROM blog_posts bp INNER JOIN
     members_posts mp
     ON mp.postId = bp.postID
WHERE mp.memberID = 1;
```

In addition:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Don't put single quotes around numeric constants.